# how to convert date() function to my timezone php

Tags: php, mysql

I noticed that when i use the following:

```
$dt = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
```

I read about converting the INI date.timezone to my timezone reading from the manual here: [date.timezone](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone) But im not confident in changing or understand it.

Then they proposed you can use `date_default_timezone_set()` so i tried the following:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Perth');
$dt = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
```

It doesnt insert the correct time. (its 4:30pm here) and it says 9:30am in the database.

full code:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
        date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Perth');
        $dt = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
        $user = $_SESSION['username'];
        $statement = $conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET last_activity = (?) WHERE username = ?");
        $statement->bind_param("ss",$dt,$user);
        $statement->execute();
        $statement->close
}
```

The time is not in my timezone. I have my database default to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` which displays the correct time in my timezone. How can i fix this?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I have changed the php ini file timezone to `'Australia/Perth'` and it doesnt work still. Do i need to do the same with apache?

Comment: mysql has its own timezone

Comment: @YourCommonSense I think i knew that in the end. However, the time in my databse with default is the correct. I changed the php ini file to ``'Australia/Perth'`` and it still doesnt work

Comment: at least you have to restart apache or php-fpm in order to chenges in php.ini would take effect

Comment: but I have to ask a stupid question: did you ever try to echo the actual value of $dt *before* looking at it in the database, and before sending it to mysqli query?

Comment: You don't need to change any system-wide setting to use a given time zone in your script. The code you've shared should work fine. The issue must be somewhere else (maybe wrong diagnostics or wrong expectations).

Answer (score 0):

You should store date & time ALWAYS in *UTC*

When it comes to display, a timezone is applied - however, two users viewing the very same date & time would use their very own timezone for this, so that the date & time corresponds to the timezone they're living in.